# How to convert a project's JavaScript loading schema to Browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify, browserify-shim

I would like to refactor a single page web application project to use Browserify as its JavaScript loading schema. I've researched Browserify but there are still things that I don't know how to solve. Allow me to describe the JavaScript loading schema that is used in the project that I want to refactor.

The first script element is inline to the generated HTML. We need that in order to pass Backend configuration to the JavaScript engine. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var OUR_COMPANY = {
  settings: {
    user: '${user}'
  }
};
</script>
```

Then we begin to load JavaScript files from a CDN and local project in an intermixable manner (notice that we use a Backend variables once again to distinguish where the JavaScript file is located):

```
<!-- resURL means CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="${properties.resURL}/js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
...
<!-- managerURL means local project -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="${properties.managerURL}/js/the_project/grids/InlineEdits.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="${properties.resURL}/js/jquery/plugin/jqgrid/v4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.m1.min.js"></script>
```

Can somebody please give me an idea on how to convert this project's JavaScript loading schema so as to replace it with Browserify?

Comment: I have done it myself here: https://github.com/miohtama/bitcoinaddress.js/blob/master/demo.js and https://github.com/miohtama/bitcoinaddress.js/blob/master/index.html#L312 - you can maybe check for inspiration. However, the devil in details and third party libraries might need some work for Browserify compatiblity.

Comment: Thanks @MikkoOhtamaa, I'll check it out and get back to you. Question: what do you mean about the "devil"?

Comment: Most JavaScript libraries out the are pure crap and when you open them in the text editor, you want to run away instead of fixing it to work with commonJS loading.